# What is mathematical term to describe this confusion?

Tags: summation

This is in reference to a question on stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445470/getting-more-data-while-converting-data-int-to-float-and-doing-division-and-mult#22445470

The following sql-scripts will generate values below, same code here in [SQLFiddle with results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/054aa/1)

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE
    (
     Students INT
    ,[Day] INT
    ,Shifts INT
    )
INSERT INTO @TableA
    VALUES  ( 129, 11, 4 )
,           ( 91, 9, 6 )
,           ( 166, 19, 8 )
,           ( 164, 26, 12 )
,           ( 146, 11, 6 )
,           ( 147, 16, 8 )
,           ( 201, 8, 3 )
,           ( 164, 4, 2 )
,           ( 186, 8, 6 )
,           ( 165, 7, 4 )
,           ( 171, 10, 4 )
,           ( 104, 5, 4 )
,           ( 1834, 134, 67 );


SELECT Students
       ,Day
       ,Shifts
       ,CAST(Day AS DECIMAL(12,1)) / CAST(Shifts AS DECIMAL(12,1)) Divs
       ,Students * (CAST(Day AS DECIMAL(12,1)) / CAST(Shifts AS DECIMAL(12,1))) StuDivs
FROM @TableA
```

---

```
    St      D   S       Div                 Stu*Div
    129     11  4       2.75000000000000    354.75000000000000
    91      9   6       1.50000000000000    136.50000000000000
    166     19  8       2.37500000000000    394.25000000000000
    164     26  12      2.16666666666666    355.33333333333224
    146     11  6       1.83333333333333    267.66666666666618
    147     16  8       2.00000000000000    294.00000000000000
    201     8   3       2.66666666666666    535.99999999999866
    164     4   2       2.00000000000000    328.00000000000000
    186     8   6       1.33333333333333    247.99999999999938
    165     7   4       1.75000000000000    288.75000000000000
    171     10  4       2.50000000000000    427.50000000000000
    104     5   4       1.25000000000000    130.00000000000000

Tot-1834    134 67      2.00000000000000    3668.00000000000000
```

So what OP wanted is for `SUM(Students*(Days/Shifts))=SUM(Students)*(SUM(DAYS)/SUM(SHIFTS))`?  So it there mathematical term to describe this and should this ever be equal to each other. My math is really hazy been too many years since last math class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for, essentially, the conditions under which

$$\sum \frac{a_i b_i}{c_i} = \frac{\sum a_i \sum b_i}{\sum c_i}.$$

We can rewrite this as

$$\sum \frac{a_i b_i}{c_i} \sum c_i = \sum a_i \sum b_i.$$

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality tells us that both sides are $\ge (\sum \sqrt{a_i b_i})^2$. Other than that, there's not much to be said. It could go either way.

For example, if our points are $(a_1, b_1, c_1) = (1, 1, 1)$ and $(a_2, b_2, c_2) = (1, 1, 1)$, then both sides are $2$ (in the original equation). If we have instead $(1, 1, 1)$ and $(1, 2, 3)$, then LHS ($5/3$) is greater than RHS ($3/2$). If we have $(1, 2, 1)$ and $(2, 1, 1)$, then LHS ($4$) is less than RHS ($9/2$).

Now, by the Cauchy-Schwarz equality condition, we do know that if all points are in the same ratio (e.g. $(1, 2, 3), (0.1, 0.2, 0.3), (4, 8, 12)$), then equality holds. However, this is only sufficient and not necessary; equality could hold between the two expressions even if Cauchy-Schwarz equality does not hold.

Unfortunately, I don't I can give much of a better answer than this: These are two different quantities, where one could be greater than, equal to, or less than the other.